# I'm having trouble with accessing my site's admin panel and CSS appears to be broken

Tags: css

I'm currently writing for Crafthub.net, and since yesterday, whenever I try to access the admin control panel (http://crafthub.net/wp-admin/), it gives me a 404.
crafthub.net/wp-content/themes/magzimus/style.css gives me a 404 too.
Trying to access any other pages shows me a broken layout, in all browsers. A picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4861882/arr.jpg
Also, everything I try to access on the site - images, as an example - give me a 404.

I tried removing OpenDNS, with no success, tried cleaning cache, Ctrl+F5, nothing. Anyone have any ideas for me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you logged into your site via its FTP or cPanel (or equivalent) to check that the files you're trying to access actually exist? If they don't exist, then you're going to need to restore from backup.

Comment: They work for me. I visit the site so I don't know why its not working for him

Comment: I've just realised that this is in fact not *your* website, in which case this isn't the place to be asking, as we're here to help people who have administrative access to their websites. The correct place for this question is over on Super User. They're more geared towards helping people who are having troubles using and accessing things. Unfortunately http://superuser.com is not one of the sites I can migrate it to automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this link? 
http://crafthub.net/wp-login.php
It worked for me but the /wp-admin/ doesn't work for me.